# My Galaxy S II is not properly allowing me to use USB storage mode - how can I fix this?

Tags: system, file-system

My phone Samsung Galaxy S2 is giving me issues with 2 removable drives(Drive E and F) shown on my computer. It also doesn't allow me to connect to USB mode.

Has anyone had this issue before with Samsung Galaxy S2?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the problem is?  It's supposed to show two drives.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that happens to me with my Galaxy Ace. I had to download Samsung Kies. I just run Kies and then works great as USB storage (you don't need to use Kies, only run it).

Comment: I found that Kies installed the proper USB drivers on my Galaxy S, but the Samsung USB Drivers package did as well.